# Excluding tag in dom tree while running xpath query

Tags: php, dom, xpath, attributes, domdocument

I have a html structure like this..

```
<div id="divid"> 
<ul id="ulid">
<li style="margin-left: 8px">
        <strong>books</strong>
</li>
<li style="margin-left: 6px">
        <a hre="">
        <span id="spanid">first line</span></a>
</li> 
<li style="margin-left: 6px">
        <a hre="">
        <span id="spanid">2nd line</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i am parsing this html part and using xpath query

```
$xpath->query('//div[@id="divid"]/ul[@id="ulid"]/li/a');
```

and the output i want is

> first line
>  2nd line

as for as i understand, my xpath query is okay if "strong" tag was not present in first "li" tag.

Note that first 'li' tag has strong tag while all other li tags have span tag in them
now i want to EXCLUDED the 'li' tag (which consists 'strong' tag in it) from my xpath query so that i can get the values of  tag below the anchor tag in li tag 
how can i modify the xpath query to make it possible? any guideline?

the original code on which i was working was...

```
<ul data-typeid="n" id="ref_1000">

     <li style="margin-left: -18px;">
                                            <a href="/s/ref=sr_ex_n_0?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327692925">‹ <span class="expand">Any Department</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                    <li style="margin-left: 8px;">
                                            <strong>Books</strong>
                                        </li>
                                    <li style="margin-left: 6px;">

                               <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A48&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327692925&amp;rnid=1000">
                        <span class="refinementLink">Crafts, Hobbies &amp; Home</span><span class="narrowValue"> (19)</span>
                                </a>
                    </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 6px;">
                               <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A10&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327692925&amp;rnid=1000">
                        <span class="refinementLink">Health, Fitness &amp; Dieting</span><span class="narrowValue"> (3)</span>

                                </a>
                    </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 6px;">
                               <a href="/s/ref=sr_nr_n_2?rh=k%3Ahow+to+grow+tomatoes%2Cn%3A283155%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A618073011%2Cn%3A%211000%2Cn%3A6&amp;bbn=1000&amp;sort=salesrank&amp;keywords=how+to+grow+tomatoes&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1327692925&amp;rnid=1000">
                        <span class="refinementLink">Cookbooks, Food &amp; Wine</span><span class="narrowValue"> (2)</span>
                                </a>
                    </li>

            </ul>
```

and i want to extract

> Crafts, Hobbies & Home etc closed in span tag

Comment: Shouldn't the xpath query be `//div[@id="divid"]/ul[@id="ulid"]/li/span`?

Comment: thanks cambraca , was a clerical error, i have fixed the code for your point now..

Comment: it seems you should just target the span: //span[@class="refinementLink"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the provided expression at face value -- *i.e.* ignoring any contradictions between the expression and your description of it -- you can use the following expression to exclude `li` elements that contain a `strong` child:

```
//div[@id="divid"]/ul[@id="ulid"]/li[not(strong)]/a
```

Comment: thanks, theoratically, it should work, and i have already tried it, tried again now, but its not working

Comment: Well, it *is* working given your provided source input. I always test my answers before posting. The most likely case is that your *actual* document differs in some way from what you've shown us. Either that, or something independent of the XPath is going wrong, but you've shown us none of that code.

Comment: thanks lwburk, i converted the code carefully, anyhow, i have pasted the original code now..